# Im having trouble while joining two tables? How to write query while the second table has only one match first table

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
select 
    doc_id, doc_name_eng 
from 
    mst_documents 
where 
    doc_id in (161,248,249,250)
```

The above query is my mst_documents resulting the specified **four documents** and the below query is the document upload table where it has only one record having only **one document** of **doc_id 250**

```sql
select 
    doc_id, document_status 
from 
    bescom_appl_upload_doc 
where 
    ack_no='EI000110259917'
```

While I tried left join to get four documents from mst_documents and  ack_no with one document

```sql
select 
    doc.doc_id, doc.doc_name_eng, bes.document_status 
from 
    mst_documents doc
left join 
    bescom_appl_upload_doc bes on bes.doc_id= doc.doc_id
where 
    doc.doc_id in (161,248,249,250) 
 and 
    ack_no ='EI000110259917' order by doc_id
```

But I get only one record from second table. Help me guys to get four documents from the mst_documents as mentioned in where condition and one document from second table like in the link **below image**

> 161   "Copy of proof of property ownership/occupancy document."
> 248   "Copy of power sanction letter from licensee."
> 249   "Copy of Estimation Sketch"
> 250   "Copy of Estimate and Technical feasibility Report."

[image]

When I join another table again I get only one record

```sql
select 
    doc.doc_id, doc.doc_name_eng, bes.document_status 
from 
    application_ht_install app
inner join 
    bescom_appl_upload_doc bes on bes.ack_no = app.ack_no and app.ack_no='EI000110207048'
left join 
    mst_documents doc on doc.doc_id = bes.doc_id 
where 
    doc.doc_id in (161,248,249,250) 
 and 
    status_code in ('INT','ACK') order by doc_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move the ack_no condition to the JOIN condition, otherwise you are filtering one row out of the entire rows after the join has been made, resulting in having only 1 row and not using the left join feature.

```
select doc.doc_id, doc.doc_name_eng, bes.document_status from mst_documents doc
left join bescom_appl_upload_doc bes on bes.doc_id= doc.doc_id 
left join application_ht_install app on bes.ack_no = app.ack_no and app.ack_no ='EI000110259917'
where doc.doc_id in (161,248,249,250) order by doc_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much...It worked but when I join other table as you said but it shows only one record am i missing something , I'LL modify the question

Comment: Nope, Nadav  The Updated query showed all the applications and its documents in bescom_appl_upload_doc, the condition ack_no doesnt worked.